# Persistent Conditional Statement Data Storage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I don't know if what I am asking here is possible or not but I thought I'd give it a go. What I would like to do is essentially something like this:

Lets say I have two cells  (A1,A2), one with a data validated list of numbers (A1): 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024

the second cell (A2) is blank.

What I would like to do is, say a user selected "2020" in the first cell(A1), and then in the second cell(A2) he typed "banana". Is there any way to have Google Sheets recall the last value of the second cell(A2) correspondent to the Data Validated value?

So say I changed the data validated value(A1) to "2022", then the second cell would be blank, but when I changed it back to "2020" then "banana" would reappear in the cell. I do NOT mean a conditional in the second cell given the first cell value. I mean is there a way to have sheets store the previous correspondent "answer" (A2) to the first cell in the ether or something and just recall it?

Sorry if this is poorly worded, I'm trying to describe it as best I can. Thanks for any help in the matter!

Edit (7/31)
Ok so let me expand on this for the situation in specific I am describing:

So I want to create a financial budget sheet that would allow a few people of the company I work for to allocate specific %'s to categories in order to budget for those categories next year. Now along with those variable categories, there are different restaurants,financial periods, and years, so here is a sample below of what a typical sheet would look like:

[image: Budget Matrix]

So basically they enter the budget year they want, the restaurant location they want, and the financial period they want. Then they can input budget percents into a column (highlighted in pink). Now here is what I want: When they get done with this particular budget year, restaurant, and period, and they change one of those data validated drop downs, I want Sheets to save the information they inputted for that specific combination of variables (Year, Restaurant, Period). Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible to achieve what you are looking for. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and try to make your question more specific.

Comment: Please provide a list of all possible input and all possible outcomes